# better way to get ol.Feature.getGeometry().j

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

ol.Feature.getGeometry().j get me the array of all coordinates. [ x, y, x, y, x, y .. ] thats work for points, or polygons. I use it to move the features and it work fast and fine. But the .j is not the "official" way to get the array. How about the best way?
edit: I dont like use getCoordinates() it give different instance of arrays for points, or polygons and i dont like to use .j because it can chance in later versions. ( so i must fix it )

use ol.js 3.5.0 and jquery for the example code

```
var x=5, y=-10;
var l=feature.getGeometry().j,n=[],b=true;
$.each(l,function(i,v){
   if(b){
      n.push(v+x);
      b=false
   }else{
      n.push(v+y);
      b=true
}});
feature.getGeometry().j=n;
```

Comment: Are you using some custom ol3 build? What is this `.j`?

Comment: No it is the normal ol3 build. If you use console.log(new ol.Feature()), or console.log(you_test_feature), you can see in the console all base functions and the class "attributs", one of it is the feature.j in it is the array of all 2D Coordinats in the style [ x,y,x,y .. ]. It is a nice way in javascript to work without the apis, becouse you see what the class can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [applyTransform()](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.geom.Polygon.html#applyTransform) allows you to modify this internal representation of the geometry.

```
var move = function(input, output, dimension) {
  for (var i = 0, ii = input.length; i < ii; i += dimension) {
    output[i] = input[i] + x;
    output[i + 1] = input[i + 1] + y;
  }
};
geometry.applyTransform(move);
```

See also [ol.TransformFunction](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.html#TransformFunction)

Comment: It see like a nice solution for the base idea to move the features. I will try it. If it work i didnt need the j. I test it later, but mark it as true answer, now. Thank you @tsauerwein :)

Comment: If you can, I'd like to see an example of this move.

Comment: The code in my answer is actually "all the magic". But anyway here is a JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5449m7em/